# jQuery live() in plain JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, live

I am trying to accomplish what the jQuery live() function can do, but in plain JavaScript.  Can anyone here help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried reading the jQuery source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little startup example

```
document.onclick = function(evt){

    evt =  evt  ||  window.event;
    var element = evt.target  ||  evt.srcElement;

};
```

wherever you click you get a reference to the element that received the click.

More useful, though, in a real scenario would be to use the [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx) method for IE, or the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
myLive("div", "click", function() { ... });
```

---

```
var liveArray = [];

function myLive(selector, type, handler) {
    liveArray.push([selector, type, handler]);
}

// this handler should fire for any event on the page, and should be attached
// to the document node
function documentAnyEvent(e) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    for (var i = 0; i < liveArray.length; i++) {
        if (target mathes the selector AND e.type matches the type) {
            // fire the handler liveArray[i][2]
        }
    }
}
```